# Google Tag Manager: Testing Adroll locally

Tags: google-tag-manager

How can I test integration of adroll with google tag manager on my local machine ? I have not found any of the documentation mentioned on google tag manager site regarding this

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to test actually? GTM has a built-in tag for Adroll.

Comment: i know gtm has built in tag for Adroll but i cannot deploy gtm directly into production without testing it

Comment: What would you like to test actually? If GTM will render the Adroll pixel correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager should work locally, depending on your envireoment setup. e.g. no blocking network firewalls etc.

1. Add the Google Tag Manager Container script to your website, just after opening `<body>` HTML Tag.
2. Configure your AdRoll Tag
3. Add the correct Trigger (Assuming All Pages by default)
4. Run Preview Mode. It is under the Publish Drop Down Menu.
5. Load the local website in a new Tab/window in the same Browser as Google Tag Manager Admin.
6. Monitor network requests to see AdRoll firing, or use the Preview window iframe to ensure your AdRoll Tag has fired.
7. Publish your Container after testing is Approved.